How to read child value in XML in C#
I am using XMLReader in C# to read value of each acctNum but the problem is it skips record.
It will skip 1st record, then read 2nd, then skip 3rd, then read 4th and so on.
<acc><acctNum>123</acctNum></acc>  
<acc><acctNum>456</acctNum></acc>  
<acc><acctNum>789</acctNum></acc>

How can I read values of all acctNum from above XML?

Can you share the code to reproduce your issue?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

SelectSingleNode on parent, and loop thought childs node
Example:

<root>
<acc><acctNum>123</acctNum></acc>
...
</root>

for each child in XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//root").Childs
    child.SelectSingleNode("acc/acctNum").InnerText
end

(XPath maybe wrong, but not problem...)

You have to add condition like this:
string xmlData = @"
        <root>
            <acc><acctNum>123</acctNum></acc>
            <acc><acctNum>456</acctNum></acc>
            <acc><acctNum>789</acctNum></acc>
        </root>";
    
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlData)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Check if the current node is an element named "acctNum"
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "acctNum")
        {
            // Move to the text content of the element
            if (reader.Read())
            {
               //read the value of the current node
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}

